# Android Studio Java: Inrico PTT Bluetooth Device Not Recognizing Voice Input

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-sco

Here's how I have configured Bluetooth connectivity in my Android app:
Java Code for Bluetooth Connection:

Here is the code to connect device

```
private void connectToDevice() {
        // Establish Bluetooth connection
        try {
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            bluetoothSocket = targetDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            listenForData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here with below code I am able to see my device

```
        AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = new AudioDeviceInfo[0];
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);
        }

        microphoneList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : audioDevices) {
            int deviceType = deviceInfo.getType();
            if (deviceType == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC ||
                    deviceType == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO ||
                    deviceType == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP) {
                microphoneList.add(deviceInfo);
            }
        }

        String[] microphoneNames = new String[microphoneList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < microphoneList.size(); i++) {
            microphoneNames[i] = microphoneList.get(i).getProductName().toString();
        }
```

Here is the recording code

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);


                    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                        // Proceed with starting Bluetooth SCO and recording
                        audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                        btnRecordPressed(null);
                    }

                    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
                    VoskActivity.this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothScoReceiver, intentFilter);



  private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothScoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);

            if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {
                // Start recording audio
                Log.d("audio connected","");

            } else if(state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                Log.d("audio disconnected","");
            }
        }
    };
```

### Expected Behavior

I expected that when I press the PTT button on my Inrico device, it would use its microphone to record my voice within the app.

### Actual Behavior

However, it seems that the recording is using the phone's built-in microphone instead of the Inrico PTT device microphone.